# Elementary won't resume after sleep

Tags: release-juno, greeter, xorg, lock

When I lock my desktop PC or let it sleep it often won't resume after waking.
Sometimes the screen just flickers and sometimes I get a underscore (_) on the screen while it does nothing.

I'm on the latest elementary OS Juno release with kernel 4.15.

My specs are:

- Intel core i7 7700
- Nvidia GTX 1080 with nvidia-430 drivers.

I did install the nvidia 430 drivers with the official Ubuntu graphics ppa, but using the same driver on Ubuntu 18.04, Xubuntu 18.04 and Lubuntu 18.04 does not give any problems.

It's noteworthy that it does not seem to happen on any other Linux distro, including normal Ubuntu 18.04. I also seem unable to access any TTY's.

Answer (score 1):

I succeed solving this issue by luis_nando's answer. What I did step-by-step:

Install netext73

$ apt-add-repository ppa:netext/netext73 && apt-get update && apt-get install netext73

$ sudo netext73

Go through the first installation

Check Hibernate in the optimizer

found on Reddit [Solution Fix](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/382e76/how_to_fix_cannot_wake_up_from_suspend_issue/)